# TONS of errors after using "npm install" from Verson 8.3.23, but application was developed with 7.0.5

Tags: angular-cli

I have a problem with building an Angular project which was developed on version 7.0.5. The current version i use is 8.3.24.

I executed npm install -g @angular/cli after NodeJS LTS installation - as usual...

When i try to install the new dependencies for the project with npm install, i always get some errors with a node-sass compilation in it's C/C++ source code.

And EVERY solution/workaround i've found in the almost whole internet leads always to the same problem... the node-sass build process starts again. (python and somthing called "gyp" is also involved in some way..)

I also tried to install npm install -g @angular/cli@7.0.5 -> the original version with that the project was developed. same result: it will also start to build the node-sass component what will fail...

So ALWAYS the same result, and there are NO, ABSOLUTELY NO exceptions!! Is ends always in the same with with each command i tried.

If you need some logs, don't hesitate to ask for.

Thank you very very much for your feedbacks!!

Best regards, Hans

Comment: I also opened a github issue regarding that problem:

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/752


If you need more details, logs, whatever, you can find them there.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a longer answer on the npm issue you raised.

Short version -

the node-sass version (v4.9.3) that you are trying is not supported on the node version (12) you are running.

You need to use node-sass v4.12.0 or higher.

If you have no control over the node-sass version try running in a supported node version, node 10.18.1 would be highest that will work with node-sass v4.9.3

edit

additional info:

you repo has a lock file, this might be pinning you to a lower version of node-sass, you could delete it and rerun `npm install`

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.

Somewhere i read that node-sass is not used anymore in Angular 8, compared to version 7.

To remove `package-lock.json` and then run `npm install` leads the the same problem, the same process will be started.

Now i have some logs, i saved them here: https://justpaste.it/1krvc

Regards, Hans

Comment: With the Angular you recommend to me, now it works. Thank you very very much, now i finally found a (possible) solution.

But does sombody know the exact way to make it run with the current NodeJS and its newser packages versions?